# MySQL, URL-encode varchar column

Tags: mysql

We have a third party system that is pulling data from their server to web client. The server is connected to a MySQL database. Data is being transfered via JSON string. Apparently, one of the columns has characters that, when introduced into JSON string, break the format. My only recourse is to fix data in the column. I was thinking of URL encoding everything. Is there an easy way of doing this in MySQL?

This is an educated guess about a behavior of a closed system. I will add another column to a data table (column_b). Then I will want to populate it with URL-encoded data from column_a. Something like this: UPDATE mytable set column_b = some_url_encode_function(column_a);

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data?

Comment: Of doing what? Do you know how exactly the data is broken and how to fix it? Doing random things never leads to solving the issue

Comment: a good json encode function should escape anything that breaks the format.. what are you using ?

Comment: This is not random. This is an educated guess about a behavior of a closed system. I will add another column to a data table (column_b). Then I will want to populate it with URL-encoded data from column_a. Something like this: UPDATE mytable set column_b = some_url_encode_function(column_a);

Comment: Erik: yes, I agree. Don't want to name the vendor, but they don't always do things right.

Comment: @zerkms Sometimes random fixes work most of the time <cough> never written any myself

Comment: [here's a link to an answer posted elsewhere that may help you with mySql URL encoding/decoding](http://brunovernay.wordpress.com/2007/04/11/urldecode-for-mysql/).  Can't vouch one way or the other for this method myself but might be of use to you.

Comment: @Sepster: I guess I had to add that I'd like to do it without altering client's server set up. It's a good solution, and I'll run it by them, but I won't hold my breath. Thanks.

Comment: @Sepster: The link you provided defines `urlDecode`. But this question is about `urlEncode`.

Comment: @dolmen from the first line of that article: "It is possible to get the urldecode() or urlencode function in MySql, the same way it exist in PHP as url_decode and url_encode".  And then after the installation instructions "Then you are free to url decode or url encode right in you SQL query !"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use alternatives as

```
/*Transforms varchar to a base64 format string*/
select to_base64(field) as encodedField

/* from_base64(encoded) does the opposite, transforming
 base64 string to the original varchar string */
```

Most languages have a base64_decode like funcion to retrieve it back.

Comment: I don't even remember the project where I encountered the issue, nor the solution to it, but I do like this suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Based in a similar response from a undecode function I provide the next code which I modified to encode:

```
-- =======================================================
-- This is a function to replace bad for good characters, this function works based in a table with the mapping
-- =======================================================
-- drop the table if it exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS urlcodemap;
-- =======================================================
-- Here the table required for the mapping
CREATE TABLE `urlcodemap` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`encoded` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`decoded` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`defEncode` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
UNIQUE KEY urlcodemapUIdx1(encoded),
KEY urlcodemapUIdx2(decoded),
KEY urlcodemapUIdx3(defEncode),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- very important that % must be the first character to replace
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%25","%", b'1');

-- the next block include the flag defEncode which indicates is necesary to encode the character
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%20"," ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%21","!", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%22","""", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%23","#", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%24","$", b'1');

INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%26","&", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%27","'", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%28","(", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%29",")", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%2A","*", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%2B","+", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%2C",",", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%2D","-", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%2E",".", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%2F","/", b'1');


INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%3A",":", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%3B",";", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%3C","<", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%3D","=", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%3E",">", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%3F","?", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%40","@", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%5B","[", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%5C","\\", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%5D","]", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%5E","^", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%5F","_", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%60","`", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%7B","{", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%7C","|", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%7D","}", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%7E","~", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%80","`", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%82","‚", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%83","ƒ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%84","„", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%85","…", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%86","†", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%87","‡", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%88","ˆ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%89","‰", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%8A","Š", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%8B","‹", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%8C","Œ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%8E","Ž", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%91","‘", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%92","’", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%93","“", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%94","”", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%95","•", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%96","–", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%97","—", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%98","˜", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%99","™", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%9A","š", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%9B","›", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%9C","œ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%9E","ž", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%9F","Ÿ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%A1","¡", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%A2","¢", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%A3","£", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%A4","¤", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%A5","¥", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%A6","¦", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%A7","§", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%A8","¨", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%A9","©", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%AA","ª", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%AB","«", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%AC","¬", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%AE","®", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%AF","¯", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B0","°", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B1","±", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B2","²", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B3","³", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B4","´", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B5","µ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B6","¶", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B7","·", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B8","¸", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%B9","¹", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%BA","º", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%BB","»", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%BC","¼", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%BD","½", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%BE","¾", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%BF","¿", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C0","À", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C1","Á", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C2","Â", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C3","Ã", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C4","Ä", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C5","Å", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C6","Æ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C7","Ç", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C8","È", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%C9","É", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%CA","", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%CB","Ë", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%CC","Ì", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%CD","Í", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%CE","Î", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%CF","Ï", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D0","Ð", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D1","Ñ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D2","Ò", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D3","Ó", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D4","Ô", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D5","Õ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D6","Ö", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D7","×", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D8","Ø", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%D9","Ù", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%DA","Ú", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%DB","Û", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%DC","Ü", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%DD","Ý", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%DE","Þ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%DF","ß", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E0","à", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E1","á", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E2","â", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E3","ã", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E4","ä", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E5","å", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E6","æ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E7","ç", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E8","è", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%E9","é", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%EA","ê", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%EB","ë", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%EC","ì", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%ED","í", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%EE","î", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%EF","ï", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F0","ð", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F1","ñ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F2","ò", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F3","ó", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F4","ô", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F5","õ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F6","ö", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F7","÷", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F8","ø", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%F9","ù", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%FA","ú", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%FB","û", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%FC","ü", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%FD","ý", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%FE","þ", b'1');
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded, defEncode) VALUES ("%FF","ÿ", b'1');


-- these characters are not required to be inserted in the table, but a URLDecode function can
-- be constructed with them

INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%30","0");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%31","1");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%32","2");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%33","3");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%34","4");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%35","5");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%36","6");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%37","7");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%38","8");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%39","9");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%41","A");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%42","B");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%43","C");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%44","D");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%45","E");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%46","F");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%47","G");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%48","H");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%49","I");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%4A","J");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%4B","K");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%4C","L");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%4D","M");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%4E","N");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%4F","O");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%50","P");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%51","Q");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%52","R");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%53","S");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%54","T");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%55","U");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%56","V");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%57","W");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%58","X");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%59","Y");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%5A","Z");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%61","a");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%62","b");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%63","c");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%64","d");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%65","e");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%66","f");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%67","g");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%68","h");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%69","i");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%6A","j");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%6B","k");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%6C","l");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%6D","m");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%6E","n");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%6F","o");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%70","p");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%71","q");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%72","r");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%73","s");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%74","t");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%75","u");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%76","v");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%77","w");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%78","x");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%79","y");
INSERT INTO urlcodemap (encoded,decoded) VALUES ("%7A","z");




-- =======================================================
-- NEXT: The function that does the magic

DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `URLENCODERCUR`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `URLENCODERCUR`(str VARCHAR(4096) CHARSET utf8) RETURNS VARCHAR(4096) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE chr VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE chrto VARCHAR(256);               
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT decoded, encoded FROM urlcodemap WHERE defEncode = b'1' ORDER BY id ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


OPEN cur1;

-- iterate through the replacements
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO chr, chrto;

    IF done THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    SET str = REPLACE(str,chr,chrto);

END LOOP;

-- required to erase the flag of NOT FOUND DATA ( mysql bug ? )
SELECT '', '' INTO chr, chrto;

CLOSE cur1;

RETURN str;
END$$


DELIMITER ;  
-- =======================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know what character is causing you the problem, you can add a `REPLACE` into your query.

```
SELECT REPLACE(theProblemColumn, 'badCharacter', 'prettyCharacter') AS sunshine
```

Comment: What if I said I have two million records and I have no idea what bad character looks like? That's one of the reasons I want to URL encode everything.

Comment: @KingJulian I would print your two million records using a dot-matrix and have a monkey find the bad characters. I would try to narrow down by divide and conquer.

Comment: OP asked "I was thinking of URL encoding everything. Is there an easy way of doing this in MySQL?". edit: And sorry, tried to add comment quickly after downvote.

Comment: @Sepster OP's question has a title of "fix bad chars in varchar column"

Comment: @njk Yes it does, but it then goes on to qualify that more specifically as I've indicated.  But if the OP accepts your answer then let me know I'll drop the downvote, but at this stage (IMO and with all due respect) this answer isn't adding much knowledge into the mix.